# Pivoting without meterpreter

Tags: network, penetration-test

Is there any way other than Meterpreter to pivot into the network? If yes, then please guide.
I already know about Meterpreter, just want to know manual methods other than this.

Comment: Second to meterpreter pivoting, one of the best methods is using SSH port forwarding http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Using_SSH_to_Port_Forward

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can always forward ports like this:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=XXXX listenaddress=Y.Y.Y.Y connectport=ZZZZ connectaddress=T.T.T.T
```

Alternately, [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) is a very powerful command-line tool which will enable you to forward ports and a lot more. Here is a sample usage:

```
socat -d -d tcp4-listen:XXXX,reuseaddr,fork,tcpwrap=socat tcp4:T.T.T.T:ZZZZ
```

Comment: Yes I have come across port forwarding ! I guess it's time now I should take it seriously. Thanks for the answer. That really helps.